# пи...то и х..во антонимы?

Tags: семантика, обсценная-лексика

Являются ли слова пи...то и х..во антонимами? 
Если да, то почему именно первое из них имеет положительное значение, тогда как второе соотносится с чем-то отрицательным?

Comment: И снова хорошие вопросы без ответа оставят.

Comment: Вопрос переоткрыт, потому что нет причин для закрытия.

Comment: А что на них, этого автора, вопросы отвечать: падают, как в бездну, как в прорубь -  без малейшего авторского отклика. Народ стал обходить их стороной: так же неинтересно...

Answer (score 1):

Эти слова действительно антонимы.

О происхождении слова "пиздатый" могу лишь сказать, что впервые услышал его на военных сборах от солдат-южан.  Это было году в 1983-м, и тогда это слово нам, питерским, было в новинку.  Судя по тому, что в дивизионе его постоянно употребляли именно кавказцы, я подозреваю, что это словечко пришло именно из тех частей страны, где доступ к женским прелестям был затруднён системой местных традиций, тогда ещё жёстких.  Посему смысл этого слова содержит в себе  коннотацию положительную, радостную, желанную.

Смысл словa "хуёво" противоположен в силу того, что исторически демонстрация детородного органа носила коннотацию негативную. И часто враждебную.  Вспомним кукиш из сложенных пальцев -- и, в частности, изображение этого жеста, выгравированное в качестве оберега на некоторых западноевропейских средневековых доспехах.  [К сожалению, не могу вспомнить, где именно видел доспех с такой гравировкой, -- но видел точно.]  В разговорном русском языке подобная коннотация утвердилась давно и прочно. Скажем, "Зашёл в сельпо, думал пиво дают -- а хуй, бля!"  Или: "Соседи жмоты, хуй они тебе чего оставят."